# How to access nested object's absolute value in powershell

Tags: powershell, nested-object

Hi I have stored some data in nested object format..Something like this

```
$group={
    "share":  {
                  "users":  [
                              {"name" : james
                                "id" :27
                              },
                              {"name" : jeni
                                "id" :18
                              },
                            ]
              }
}
```

when I try to retrieve the value of share or users it returns null

The output for pinging $group is

```
{
    "share":  {
                  "users":  [
                                "System.Collections.Hashtable",
                                "System.Collections.Hashtable"
                            ]
              }
}
```

How do I retrieve the value of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
$group = @'
{
    "share":{
        "users":[
            {
                "name":"james",
                 "id": "27"
            },
            {
                "name":"jeni",
                "id":"18"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'@

$group | 
ConvertFrom-Json

<#
share                   
-----                   
@{users=System.Object[]}
#>


$group | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty Share

<#
users                                      
-----                                      
{@{name=james; id=27}, @{name=jeni; id=18}}
#>


$group | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty Share | 
Select -ExpandProperty Users

<#
name  id
----  --
james 27
jeni  18
#>


$group | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty Share | 
Select -ExpandProperty Users | 
Select Name

<#
name 
---- 
james
jeni
#>


$group | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty Share | 
Select -ExpandProperty Users | 
Select id

<#
id
--
27
18
#>


($group | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -ExpandProperty Share | 
Select -ExpandProperty Users)[0]

<#
name  id
----  --
james 27
#>
```

***As per my comment ***

```
# Dot reference the object

$group = @'
{
    "share":{
        "users":[
            {
                "name":"james",
                 "id": "27"
            },
            {
                "name":"jeni",
                "id":"18"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'@


(($group | ConvertFrom-Json)).share

<#
users                                      
-----                                      
{@{name=james; id=27}, @{name=jeni; id=18}}
#>



(($group | ConvertFrom-Json)).share.Users

<#
name  id
----  --
james 27
jeni  18
#>



(($group | ConvertFrom-Json)).share.Users.Name
<#
james
jeni
#>

(($group | ConvertFrom-Json)).share.Users.id
<#
27
18
#>

(($group | ConvertFrom-Json)).share.Users[0]

<#
name  id
----  --
james 27
#>



(($group | ConvertFrom-Json)).share.Users | Select-Object -First 1

<#
name  id
----  --
james 27
#>
```

Comment: But I don't get something like above. Here is my output                                                                     $share_group|ConvertFrom-Json|Select -ExpandProperty Share

users
-----
{System.Collections.Hashtable, System.Collections.Hashtable}

Comment: If you need to add more code, use your existing answer vs the comment section. However, notice the difference between how I assigned the JSON string to the variable vs how you are showing it.  Meaning, the way you are assigning the JSON string to your variable is not correct. If you do that in the ISE or VSCode, it will show as errors. BTW, even what I posted can be shortened. See my update for you.

Comment: No worries. Glad it got you going.